# 7zip only asks me for a password once when I open an encrypted file

Tags: encryption, zip, 7-zip, password-protection

I archived some files on my laptop and encrypted them using 7zip and the first time I tried to open a file, it asks for the password, but after that it never asks for a password. Is there a way to fix this?

What's strange is the exact same method worked fine on my old laptop (which is Windows 7), but not on my new laptop (Windows 8)

Comment: Very [related](http://superuser.com/questions/70313/7zip-doesnt-ask-me-for-password-for-a-zip-i-encrypted-while-double-clicking-it?rq=1)

Comment: I tried archiving twice but I had the same problem :/

Comment: also http://superuser.com/questions/871816/how-to-prevent-7-zip-encrypted-zip-file-passwords-from-being-stored-on-the-hard "You can open an encrypted ZIP file. But to get to the data inside the ZIP file in any useful way you'll be prompted for a password" So you need to check to see if your archive is actually password protected, and apon extraction see if it fully extracts, then see if  the data it extracted is actually valid. Although it would usually warn when the password entered wrong, it can (not will) make a wrongly extracted mess, with the wrong password, it just wont be  correct..

Answer (score 0):

### Background

I also experienced the same issue. On Windows 11 I downloaded and ran "7z2201-x64.exe". After, I added my folder to an archive and password-protected it. If I launch windows file explorer and navigate into the zip file to a password-protected file, the prompt asks for a password. However, it does not prompt again for any files in the zip after the first successful password input/authentication.

### Suggested approach

Instead of opening your zip from windows explorer, open it with 7zip itself. Right-click and select 7zip -> "open archive". This will open the 7zip explorer. You can do the same thing here as windows explorer. After you put in a password for a file, all files will remain unlocked here as well. However, this will only be in the 7zip explorer session. That means, if you go to the zip file through windows explorer, you will see they are still locked. Also, once you close the 7zip explorer, the session context will drop so new sessions will re-prompt for a password.

This also suggests that if you use windows explorer, then you may have to terminate your windows session for the password lock to take effect again. Which is why I suggested using the 7zip approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the files, so it will ask you for a password.

If you access the files and enter the password without specifying the folder, it will be extracted to temp.

And if you open it again it redirects you to this file.

Answer (score -4):

Windows keeps zip file without security after the first password was input, use .7z instead.